# How to achieve "public static" member visibility using Xtext?

Tags: xtext, scoping

Within my DSL There are packages (one per file), imports, classes and class members. 
Say one file contains package p1 which contains class c1 and class c1 has a member m1. Another file contains package p2 which contains class c2 which has a member m2.

I would like the member m1, to have a visibility like that of a member from Java modified with `public static`. Meaning from Package p2, after including  p1, in Class c2, the member m2 could have a value that could be a reference to m1 (m2=c1.m1).

Imports work, but I can only see the elements directly contained by the imported entity (including p1.c1.* would fix my problem but I don't want to do it this way) Is there another solution for this type of scoping?

Comment: how does your grammar look like

Comment: @ChristianDietrich In a simplified example I would like to reference types from other classes in other packages.  

Package:  
 'package' name=QualifiedName  
 imports+=Import*  
 classes+=Class*;  
    
Class:'class' name=ID '{'elements+=Element*  '}';  
QualifiedName:ID ('.' ID)*;  
QualifiedNameWithWildCard:QualifiedName ('.*')?;  
Import: 'import' importedNamespace=QualifiedNameWithWildCard;  
Element: Type|Reference ;  
Type:'type' name=ID ;  
Reference: type=[Type] name=ID;

Answer (score 0):

```
Reference: type=[Type]
```

is short for

```
Reference: type=[Type|ID]
```

the `|ID`means that an `ID` will be parsed.
an `ID` does not allow dots (`.`)

thus you may want to change the grammar to

```
Reference: type=[Type|QualifiedName]
```